# How to deal with equals when meet polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I meet a problem and I feel confused.
Things like this:

```
class animal and 
class cat extends animal
```

Now assumed I have already overridden the equals method both in animal and cat.

See:

```
cat a = new cat("white","Tom")   //cat has specific property name    
cat b = new cat("black","Jim")    
a.equals(b)                      //return false    
animal c = (animal)a             //animal has no name property
```

`c.equals(a)` and `a.equals(c)` all return true

this is weird, since you can not say an animal is a cat.

And I learn that cast in Java does not change the class of the object. so  `c.getClass()` still returns cat. But something can do with this? I want a false when comparing animal with cat.

Thanks

Comment: But `c` refers to an actual `Cat` object.  You can't turn off polymorphism in Java.

Comment: Casting doesn't change what an object is.  You have an animal that _is a `Cat`._

Comment: Not only that, `a` and `c` refer to *the same identical object*.

Comment: @WindGrin Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your codes:

```
cat a = new cat("white","Tom")   
cat b = new cat("black","Jim")    
a.equals(b)                       
animal c = (animal)a
```

You can visualize it as:

***cat a = new cat("white","Tom");***

```
+------------+
| white, tom | <--- a (Cat)
+------------+
```

***cat b = new cat("black","Jim");***

```
+------------+
| black, jim | <--- b (Cat)
+------------+
```

***animal c = (animal)a;***

```
+------------+
| white, tom | <--- a (Cat)
+------------+ <--- c (Animal)
```

> c.equals(a) and a.equals(c) all return true

Since `a` and `c` refers to the same object, it will always be true no matter how you cast it. Casting it as `Animal` is merely like telling the compiler "hey, treat this Cat as an Animal" (But it is still referring to the same animal, hence the equals method always gives you true).

If you are not overriding the equals method from class `Object`, The default implementation looks like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

If you want to override it by comparing the `name` and `color` of the Cat, you can do something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof Cat))
        return false;
    Cat c = Cat(obj);
    return (this.getName().equals(c.getName()) && this.getColor().equals(c.getColor()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks,this really helps.

Answer (score 2):

Java is not comparing the reference variable types; it is comparing the objects they reference. In your case, both `Animal a` and `Cat c` are both `Cat`. Further, they both reference the *exact same object*.

Comment: Thanks. It is so kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to override the equals method in the super class to implement the desired equals operation. (i.e comparing the strings that contain the name and color)

Answer (score 0):

In everyday language:

You asked java if the animal c is the same animal as a. 
`a.equals(c)`
Java says **yes** because it is the same animal. 
 You did NOT ask Java if all animals are Cats. You asked Java if that this Animal is a Cat. The answer is yes, because it was a Cat (right from the beginning). 
If you create an animal and compare it to a cat

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Cat c = new Cat();
a.equals(c);//This might give you false
```

you might get false because **this** animal may not always be cat.